# Differentiating between different USB accessory attached to phone

Tags: android

I am doing a project in android studio which requires me to check if a printer and a usb fingerprint scanner is attached to the device. How can I check if the device connected is printer or scanner ?

i have used USBManager and UsbDevice to get the list of all connected devices but not able to check the type of devices connected.

Comment: Why not? If you have the `UsbDevice` you can get the device class and subclass, product ID, and vendor ID--what else besides that do you need?

Comment: Could be anything since IIRC there's no specific base/subclass for biometric devices. Device identification is often a matter of a collection of vendor/product IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official **UsbConstants** [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbConstants.html)

```
int Class = device.getDeviceClass();
```

ex : if printer : `USB_CLASS_PRINTER`  : `Constant Value: 7`

Comment: this for printer, and what will be the usbConstant for fingerprint scanner

Comment: this is why i left the link of the documentation , that can help you more for another constant

Comment: I read the documentation and not able to get which constant i have to choose for scanner.

Comment: USB_CLASS_CONTENT_SEC, content security constant can be used for fingerprint scanner ?

Comment: just connect your scanner and get the int constant and search for it , it may be USB_CLASS_CONTENT_SEC  or USB_CLASS_HID

Comment: you are welcome , i think yeah since you will get the constant int